# Cyclo for with inside ajax, the callback return a wrong result

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I tried to create a jquery plugIn that load multiple feed rss (they are flexible can be 1 or 2 or 3 ect...), for create an html that show the news feed loaded. My target is having the possibility to load multiple rss feed (xml) and display them by html. When I tried seem that the callback is overwrite,I received 2 results but equal.

Example:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.getFeed = function(Obj){
        var
            arrOpt = Obj.arrayOptions,
            arrOptLng = arrOpt.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < arrOptLng; i++){
            var 
                index = i,
                Opt = arrOpt[i],
                feedUrl = Opt.feed,
                sucFnc = Opt.callback,
                $cnt = this;

            console.log(index);
            // here:
            // 0
            // 1

            $.ajax({
                url:feedUrl,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success:function(data){
                    sucFnc(data,$cnt,Opt,index);
                },
                error:function(){
                    $cnt.html('error');
                }
            });
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

function feedManipulation(){
    console.log(index)
    // here:
    // 1
    // 1
}

/* DOM LOADED */
$(function(){
    $('.news').getFeed({ // Activation getFeed
        arrayOptions:[{
            feed:'http://feed', 
            callback:feedManipulation,
            imgDefault:'http://img',
            nArtc:1
        },{
            feed:'http://feed', 
            callback:feedManipulation,
            imgDefault:'http://img',
            nArtc:1
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, I wrote this question and I created the solution so I would explain.
In this code I removed the cyclo for and I create a function that contain the ajax call.
The first time that I trigger the ajax function I pass an argument to the ajax function with inside an object that I used to set the plugIn (lock on the bottom) whereas my ajax function is itself calls, before sending the same object to the ajax function I change some information like "Opt.index" creating in this way a ajax cyclo. Is it really usefull ;) use it.

```
(function($){
        $.fn.getFeed = function(Obj){

            // Options object
            Opt = new Object();
            Opt.index = 0;
            Opt.$cnt = this;
            Opt.arrOpts = Obj.arrayOptions;
            Opt.arrOptLng = Opt.arrOpts.length;
            Opt.arrOpt = Opt.arrOpts[Opt.index];
            Opt.feedUrl = Opt.arrOpts[Opt.index].feedUrl;

            // ajax call
            cycloAjax(Opt);
        }

        /* ajax cyclo */
        function cycloAjax(Obj){
            $.ajax({
                url: Obj.feedUrl,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success:function(data){
                    feedManipulation(data,Obj.$cnt,Obj);

                    if(Obj.index < Obj.arrOptLng - 1){
                        Obj.index++;
                        Obj.arrOpt = Obj.arrOpts[Obj.index];
                        Obj.feedUrl = Obj.arrOpts[Obj.index].feedUrl;
                        cycloAjax(Obj);
                    }
                    else{
                        completeLoadFeeds(Obj.$cnt,Obj);
                    }
                },
                error:function(){
                    Obj.$cnt.html('<p>error</p>');
                }
            });
        }

        .
        .
        .

    })(jQuery);

    /* DOM LOADED */
    $(function(){
        $('.news').getFeed({ // Activation getFeed
            arrayOptions:[{
                feed:'http://feed', 
                callback:feedManipulation,
                imgDefault:'http://img',
                nArtc:1
            },{
                feed:'http://feed', 
                callback:feedManipulation,
                imgDefault:'http://img',
                nArtc:1
            }]
        });
    });
```